# Access ERC721 using OpenSeas library

Tags: ethereum

Does anyone experienced in OpenSeaJS library to retrieve assets or collections for the ERC721 token?
I'm trying to retrieve my test tokens(721) on Ropsten network, I found this library on Internet called OpenSeaJs, wondering anyone came across that. Please advise, otherwise, is there any better ways?
Does OpenSeaJs supports Ropsten network?

Answer (score 0):

Currently OpenSea.js only supports the Rinkeby test network and the main Ethereum network. I'd encourage using Rinkeby because it's fast and most test ERC721 contracts and a growing number of ERC1155 items live there now. Just use `Network.Rinkeby` when (getting started)[https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js#getting-started], and https://faucet.rinkeby.io/ to get 20 free Rinkeby ETH!